# randomly move images in a fixed area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to move images randomly in an area. But I need to show atleast 3 images always. Here is what I had done:

**HTML**

```
<div class="fade">Image 1</div>
<div class="fade">Image 2</div>
<div class="fade">Image 3</div>
<div class="fade">Image 4</div>
<div class="fade">Image 5</div>
<div class="fade">Image 6</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function fadeInDiv() {
    var divs = jQuery('.fade');
    var elem = divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length));
    if (!elem.is(':visible')) {
        elem.prev().remove();
        elem.fadeIn(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), fadeInDiv);
    } else {

        elem.fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), function() {
            elem.before('<div>&nbsp;</div>');
            fadeInDiv();
        });
    }
})();
```

This code fadein and fadeout images randomly as a result show 2 images at a time sometimes 1 image at a time sometime 3. I need to show 3 images with in 6 images every time with fadein fadeout functionality.

Here is how my home page look like:

```
Image1          Image2


       Image3
```

I want it to look like:

```
       Image1

Image2        Image3
```

or

```
       Image1

       Image2  Image3
```

or any other pattern with this images

Answer (score 1):

Try a recursive algorithm with delay lengths depending on the random order of the objects:

```js
window.refresh = function(delay) {
  delay *= 1000;
  var doms = [];
  var randos = [];
  var index = 0;

  function fadeout() {
    if (index < 3) {
      var random = $(doms.get(randos[index]));
      $(random).delay(delay + 200 * index).fadeTo(200, 0, function() {
        $(random).css("visibility", "hidden");
      });
      doms = doms.not(random);
      index++;
      fadeout(doms);
    }
  }

  doms = $('.grid-item');
  doms.css("visibility","visible");
  doms.css("opacity","1");
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * doms.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < doms.length; i++) {
    while (randos.indexOf(num) > -1) {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * doms.length);
    }
    randos.push(num);
  }
  fadeout();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Image 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Image 6</div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="refresh(0)">Trigger Animation</button>
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" placeholder="Time in Seconds">
<button onclick="refresh($(this).prev().val())">Trigger Delayed Animation</button>
```

Comment: Keep clicking 'Run code snippet' to repeat the animation.

Comment: ok thanks oMiKey . But I need it on page load and three at a time. Can you help with that also. Thanks

Comment: Thanks oMiKey you saved my time. One little thing I need to know. As if now images fadein and out when page is refreshed or reloads. H
ow about if I want it run automatically i.e without page refresh it fadein and out after a span of time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello oMiKey can you please help?

Comment: Yes indeed... i'll be programming in a few moments.

Comment: OK I edited it to be one function with a seconds-delay option. If you don't want delay just put 0. It adds the delay time to the random fading times. The top button will trigger a reanimation instantly by calling the refresh function, which first makes all images visible (css - visibility:visible; opacity:1) then fades them out as before.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use css properties to change their position on the screen.

You ll have to precise their positionning style, IE absolute.

`elem.css('top','15px')` and `elem.css('left','15px')` are the propers method to move objects on screen. You ll adjust the `15px` to the value you ll need. It s relative to the top-left corner of your screen.

`fadeIn` / `fadeOut` only change opacity property of those objects on the screen.